# Javascript & lodash ... cast _.find result to boolean

Tags: javascript

Is this acceptable practice to cast find results to boolean. As I'm new to JS I'm unsure if there are any gotchas. This currently works, but is it acceptable and is there a better practice?

```
        collection.contains = function collectionHas(name, value, key) {
            key = _.isString(key) ? key : 'app_id';
            if (_.has(store, name)) {
                return !!_.find(store[name], function(item, k) {
                    return item[key] == value;
                });
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you shouldn't directly cast the result of a `find` operation to a boolean. For example, if you are searching an array for the number `0`, then on success the returned value will be `0` which is coerced into the boolean `false`. Learn more about type coercion in JavaScript [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20&%20grammar/ch4.md).

You should thus use the `===` operator to do a strict comparison against `undefined`, which is what `_.find` returns when it doesn't find anything. From the [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#find) docs:

> Returns
>   (*): Returns the matched element, else undefined.

So your code would become:

```
    collection.contains = function collectionHas(name, value, key) {
        key = _.isString(key) ? key : 'app_id';
        if (_.has(store, name)) {
            return undefined !== _.find(store[name], function(item, k) {
                return item[key] == value;
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: makes perfect sense, thank you for the explanation. Article link is a godsend - cheers

Comment: I have raised a ticket with lodash suggesting that `_.includes` should support an identity predicate function (https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2305).

Answer (score 8):

Use `_.some`, it works exactly like find but returns a boolean